# Google Street View transition / zoom fade out transition

Tags: zooming, transition, fade, virtual-reality, google-street-view

I have created 360 vr image with a few hotspots using a-frame.

Now I am trying to add the zoom fade transition like google street view for the hotspot changing image, but I've looking all over internet and tried a dozen times failing, so I need your help.

(**P.s. I am not a code developer, which means I am super newbie, so u might need to treat me like a idiot/baby to guide me.)

```js
document.querySelector('#here1').addEventListener('click', function () {
   document.querySelector('#pano').setAttribute('src','#pano1'); 
     document.querySelector('#here1').setAttribute('visible','false');
        
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Kempas Residence</title>
   <meta name="description" content="360&deg; Image - A-Frame" />
   <script src="https://aframe.io/aframe/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
    
 </head>
  
 <body>
  <a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
    <a-assets>
      <audio id="click-sound" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/audio/click.ogg"></audio>
      <img id="pano1" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6128c6fd-5c0c-424e-823f-27840db2dfcb%2Fpano2.jpg?v=1590040717497"/>
      <img id="pano2" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6128c6fd-5c0c-424e-823f-27840db2dfcb%2Fpano1.jpg?v=1590040608692"/>
    </a-assets>
      
      
      
  <a-sky src="#pano2" id="pano" rotation="0 -85 0"></a-sky>
      
  <a-camera id="camera" drag-look-controls reverse-mouse-drag="true" visible="false" zoom="1">
    <a-cursor id="cursor">
      <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1" dur="150"></a-animation>
      <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1" dur="1500"></a-animation>
    </a-cursor>
  </a-camera>
  
  <a-octahedron id="here1" position="23 4 -0.95" scale="-0.5 1 -0.5" opacity="1" animation="property: position; dir: alternate; from: 23 4 -0.95; to: 23 5 -0.95; dur: 750; loop: true" color="#00E4FF"></a-octahedron>
  </a-scene>

   </body>
```